Cumulative count distinct with condition in Bigquery
I'm trying to obtain the cumulative number of distinct customers who bought a product by category within 3 months / within 6 months / within 12 months after the end date of campaign according to the corresponding category.
Input table:



product
order_date
client
end_campaign




A
2024-01-01
001
2024-03-01


A
2024-01-01
002
2024-03-01


A
2024-01-04
003
2024-03-01


A
2024-03-01
001
2024-03-01


A
2024-03-04
003
2024-03-01


A
2024-04-01
003
2024-03-01


A
2024-07-04
007
2024-03-01


A
2024-07-09
008
2024-03-01


B
2024-03-07
001
2024-05-01


B
2024-05-09
006
2024-05-01


B
2024-06-20
008
2024-05-01


B
2024-06-20
009
2024-05-01


B
2024-08-20
009
2024-05-01


B
2024-08-21
010
2024-05-01



Here's what I'm trying to achieve:



product
end_campaign
cum_dist_count_3M
cum_dist_count_6M




A
2024-03-01
2
4


B
2024-05-01
3
4



The DB is in BigQuery StandardSQL.
Any help is much appreciated!
WITH firstseen AS (   SELECT product, 
         client,
         case when order_date >= end_campagne then min(order_date) else null end as first_date   FROM sample_table   GROUP BY 1,2 )

SELECT DISTINCT product, 
                COUNT(client) OVER (PARTITION by Product ORDER BY first_date) as daily_cumulative_count  FROM firstseen ORDER BY 1


This isn't really cumulative as such (that would be a running sum using Window Functions). It's just a simple COUNT(DISTINCT with a condition.
In some DBMSs you can use COUNT(DISTINCT with a FILTER, but in BigQuery you need a CASE.
SELECT
  product,
  end_campaign,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN end_campaign AND DATE_ADD(end_campaign, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) THEN client END) AS cum_dist_count_3M,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN end_campaign AND DATE_ADD(end_campaign, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN client END) AS cum_dist_count_6M
FROM sample_table st
GROUP BY
  product,
  end_campaign;

I suspect it may be faster to aggregate by client first then aggregate again
SELECT
  product,
  end_campaign,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN cum_count_3M > 0 THEN 1 END) AS cum_dist_count_3M,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN cum_count_6M > 0 THEN 1 END) AS cum_dist_count_6M
FROM (
    SELECT
      product,
      end_campaign,
      client,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN end_campaign AND DATE_ADD(end_campaign, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) THEN client END) AS cum_count_3M,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN end_campaign AND DATE_ADD(end_campaign, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN client END) AS cum_count_6M
    FROM sample_table st
    GROUP BY
      product,
      end_campaign,
      client
) st
GROUP BY
  product,
  end_campaign;

db<>fiddle

just a small pointer, INTERVAL '3 MONTH' doesn't work in BigQuery syntax, you need to drop the quote marks

thanks very much, there's no way to transpose 3M/6M/12M directly from column to row ? the columns become product/ end_campagne/period /cum_nb_client, and in 'period', we have values 3M, 6M, 12M.

I'm not sure what you mean, it sounds like you might need some kind of join. The above matches what you originally asked, if you want something else I suggest you create a new question with a [mcve] containing your data and what result you uactually want.
